# Nested subquery to find MIN of data in one field

Tags: subquery, min

I have these fields in my data:

PT#  DCFY

123  2013

453  2011

562  2010

495  2014

934  2015

I am needing to add a field for the minimum value of all of values in DCFY. Such as:

PT#  DCFY MINFY

123  2013 2010

453  2011 2010

562  2010 2010

495  2014 2010

934  2015 2010

I know I need to do a nested query but I am not good at them. Can someone tell me how to do it to get this?

Answer (score 0):

```
select PT#, DCFY,(select MIN(DCFY) from Data) as MINYR from Data.
```

This gives me:

```
PT# DCFY MINFY
123 2013 2010
453 2011 2010
562 2010 2010
495 2014 2010
934 2015 2010
```

which works but if I add code for `WHERE DCFY between 2012 and 2015` it still gives me 2010 for MINFY, which is incorrect. With the `WHERE` clause added, it should instead give me 2013 for the MINFY.

Answer (score 0):

Ok cool. I still don't see what the statement is, but assuming it something like this:

```
select col1, col2, min(col2) over()
from table
```

the over() function should look over the entire resultset and give you the min value of that column.

Comment: OMG! That worked! I have searched online all day to find a solution to this. I never came across using over() to get it to work with a WHERE clause that narrows my data. Thank you so so much.